# how to change displaytag sortproperty link

Tags: java, displaytag

I am using display tag in my application. In that i need to sort the table contents based on the column header click. Column header has link navigation. Instead i need to submit the form while clicking on the table column header. How can we achieve it.

As of now, my application craetes the table like this,

```
<display:table id="data" name="lstEntities"
                        sort="external" uid="row" htmlId="rowid" class="tborder"
                        excludedParams="*" style="width:100%"
                        pagesize="${pageCriteria.recordsPerPage}" partialList="true"
                        size="${pageCriteria.totalRecords}" export="false"
                        requestURI="prestigeBrandListMDA.action">
                        <display:column property="brandId" sortName="brand.brandId"
                            sortable="true" titleKey="table.title.brandId"
                            style="width:100px" />

<thead>
<tr>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="prestigeBrandListMDA.action?d-16544-p=1&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-n=1&amp;d-16544-s=brand.brandId">Sales Brand Id</a></th>
```

instead i need the link like below

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:submitform(prestigeBrandListMDA.action?d-16544-p=1&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-n=1&amp;d-16544-s=brand.brandId)">Sales Brand Id</a></th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that using displaytag. Use the JQuery [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to change links on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i used Jquery to achieve this functionality.thanks.i used the following code to achieve it.

```
$('.sortable').each(function(event){ 
                var obj = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); 
                var urltext = 'javascript:submitform("'+contextPath+'/'+obj+'\")';  
                $(this).find('a').attr('href', urltext);
            });
```